# Pull EXIF photo data for ArcGIS Pro Reports

Tags: arcgis-pro, attachments, reports, exif

I was hoping to create a Report in ArcGIS Pro that could take photo EXIF information from an attachment and add it to the report.  Similar to how Survey123 report does it with the ${picture|getValue:”y” and ${picture|getValue:”x” and ${picture|getValue:”direction”} options (as examples).

Does anyone know how to do this?  Is there possibly a work around with an Arcade function in the Dynamic Picture element?

This would allow us to move over from generating/using report credits in Survey123 and then our office would only have to work with Field Map App and ArcGIS Pro. I posted the same question on Esri Community as well.

Comment: You state that you want to stop using Survey123 reports- OK that makes sense.  But will you still be using a survey in Survey123 for collecting the data (including taking the photos)?

Comment: Collecting data through Survey123 is still an option. I was curious about using the smart forms through ArcGIS Online (Or Field Maps Designer I think it’s called) and moving away from Survey123 all together (that way data collection is done with one app only). I have a hyperlink connecting to the Survey123 form as part of the pop-up in field maps and that can still be used). The reason I thought about moving over from Survey123 was because in Field Maps you can see the related table and even if all the fields are read-only, you can still add photos and that messes up the Survey123 report.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** (if capturing the data in Survey123, but generating reports in ArcGIS Pro)

The easiest way to do this would be to modify the survey itself to use the `@exif` version of the `pulldata()` function to pull the required EXIF elements from a survey photo question into their own survey questions automatically (ie in a calculation).  This will remove the need to do any post-processing of the data and make your reporting trivially easy.  For more information, see the `pulldata()` section at:  https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-blog/working-with-exif-image-metadata-in-survey123-for/ba-p/891687

After making this change to the survey, all the EXIF data (for subsequent survey collections) will be automatically included in attributes in the survey data.  Therefore it will all be easily available as attributes in ArcGIS Pro.  Therefore you can use it easily for ArcGIS Pro reporting.

**Option 2:** (if not capturing the data in Survey123)

If you cannot modify the survey, as in Option 1 above, or if you have photos from already-submitted surveys that you need to process, or for non-Survey123 data, then...

Convert your photos to points (in a point feature class) using the [Photos to Points](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/geotagged-photos-to-points.htm) tool.

The feature class produced by this tool includes attributes for coordinates, direction, date/time, etc.  This should be all the data you need for your report.

Note, however, that this tool requires a folder of photos for its input, not a table of photo attachments.  So firstly, you will need to convert the table of photo attachments to a folder of image files.  The entire process is described at:  https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-survey123-questions/photo-attachments-to-points/td-p/1024991

Comment: I apologize as I may not understand your answer. Our office has created a report through Survey123 and that’s what we are currently doing. I want to try to move away from Survey123 and use ArcPro Reports instead.
Our data is a polygon feature (farm field) and every year we have to do an irrigation report to see what they are growing. There is a relate table with picture attachments as part of that and in Survey123 you can get location info out of the picture and set it in the report (but I’d like to do that through ArcGIS Pro Reports instead if that’s possible)? Does this make more sense

Comment: If your follow the instructions in this answer, then the data you need will be available in ArcGIS Pro.  So therefore you can do what you wish in ArcGIS Pro reports.  I've added a paragraph to the answer that I hope makes it clearer.  This assumes that you will still be using Survey123 to collect the data (take the photos), and then using ArcGIS Pro (NOT Survey123) to run the reports.  Are you using Survey123 to collect the data (and take the photos)?  If so, then this answer should work for you.

Comment: Thank you!! I understand now, and best option sounds like still using Survey123 in some way (in this case data collection still). Smart forms with ArcGIS Online I don’t believe can do pulldata() either.